# Permanently add bower proxy

Tags: bower, bower-install

How do I permanently add bower proxy to my system so I do not have to edit the .bowerrc file for every project and add

```
{
 "proxy":"http://<proxy>:<port>",
 "https-proxy":"https://<proxy>:<port>",
}
```

I have added the proxys to my OS with:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<proxy_url>:<port>
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy_url>:<port>
```

But it seams bower does not get it. Thank you in advance for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `.bowerrc` file in your home folder (it will work on Windows as well).

From http://bower.io/docs/config/:

> Placement & Order
>
> The config is obtained by merging multiple configurations by this
>   order of importance:
>
> - CLI arguments via --config
> - Environment variables
> - Local .bowerrc located in the current working directory
> - All .bowerrc files upwards the directory tree
> - .bowerrc file located in user’s home folder (~)
> - .bowerrc file located in the global folder (/)
>
> Example of CLI arguments:
>
> - --config.endpoint-parser=
> - --config.storage.cache=
>
> Example of valid environment variables:
>
> - bower_endpoint_parser is evaluated as endpoint-parser
> - bower_storage__cache is evaluated as storage.cache